# Typescript: Use keyof value in adjacent property type

Tags: typescript

I have a dynamic navigation stack like this:

```
const fullKYCStack = [
  {
    name: 'Account Credentials Screen',
    component: AccountCredentialsScreen,
  },
  {
    name: 'Verify Email Screen',
    component: VerifyEmailScreen,
  },
  ...
}
```

There is an object of possible names:

```
type KYCStackParamList = {
  'Account Credentials Screen': undefined;
  'Verify Email Screen': undefined;
  ...
};
```

I would like to create a type such that each item in the array is typed according to the "name" that is used, so the first item in the array would have this type:

```
type AccountCredentialsScreen = {
  name: 'Account Credentials Screen';
  component: (
    props: NativeStackScreenProps<KYCStackParamList, 'Account Credentials Screen'>,
  ) => JSX.Element;
}
```

I tried to make a generic type for each item:

```
interface KYCScreen<K extends keyof KYCStackParamList> {
  name: K;
  component: (
    props: NativeStackScreenProps<KYCStackParamList, K>,
  ) => JSX.Element;
}
```

However sadly the generic isn't inferred when applying it to the array:

```
const fullKYCStack: KYCScreen[] = [
  {
    name: 'Account Credentials Screen',
    component: AccountCredentialsScreen,
  },
  {
    name: 'Verify Email Screen',
    component: VerifyEmailScreen,
  },
  ...
}
```

Gives: "Generic type 'KYCScreen' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)"

How can I tell Typescript to get this type value from the "name" property for each item?

Comment: If you were to use Typescript 4.9, you could use the `satisfies KYCScreen<any>[]` notation to hint the compiler to validate the types while keeping the types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really possible create a generic type where you don't have to specify an explicit type when using like this. The alternative would be to compute a *union* type of all possible combinations.

```
type KYCScreen = {
  [K in keyof KYCStackParamList]: {
    name: K,
    component: (
      props: NativeStackScreenProps<KYCStackParamList, K>,
    ) => JSX.Element;
  }
}[keyof KYCStackParamList]
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwtgDg9gTgLgAjgTwgUwQbwQOQIZwgBuaAynHgMYDWplMaaAdgAoxQQDOCAvggGbswCAOQABBlTgBaJniIgA5gRBQmAejmES0zhRoiA3MGAp0CANIBNAMLkq1Fnhh4wAGRB6EAXizAEogCClJRQAK5MiDYMACbMhHgANtx0DMwiAFwIEXH8IExoMcYBIgBqaDAg-MgIAKJgeCCJCKmMTJnZTLn5hcY8xqaoGNZ29G0%20fgEA2hYI%20QjUaMhQ-Ja29jROLu6ecAC6WZj%20AQhyYGhZFgA0xwGhkGrxWQAUtycQ7FxZ%20Npk%20rRjZhsDicAA8Iw2jmcrg8eiulgAfDcTggAJQ%20BEIABSpAAGgA6WqJNDnSLFXjAHhTRbLVYQ-5bGG7PYmEyhJhefhhRKJekOS7rQFMKZ7CZTY5HFFnC5BELhSIIaKFeIgJIpIUiZEne7QAqRLLBUIROBKuKRVXJVrMLU8LWSk7SrJlCpVGr1RrNK3tLV3KAPPVwLLlSrVd1NL02m48IA)